# Como puedo realizar la paginación de una tabla con mas de 4000 registros usando post en en lugar de get

Tags: php, javascript, json

Como puedo realizar la paginación de una tabla con mas de 4000 registros usando el evento post, eh visto casos con Get, pero no quiero mostrar nada en la URL cada que cambio de paginación

Comment: Conceptualmente, la paginación se hace con un método *GET* porque es una "petición de datos". Si no quieres que la *URI* sea del estilo `<host>?page=X&size=X`, quizás podrías contemplar poner esos dos parámetros como *header* de la petición...

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento.